# mongodb count number of documents for every category

Tags: mongodb

My collection looks like this:

```
   {  
   "_id":ObjectId("5744b6cd9c408cea15964d18"),
   "uuid":"bbde4bba-062b-4024-9bb0-8b12656afa7e",
   "version":1,
   "categories":["sport"]
   }, 
   {
   "_id":ObjectId("5745d2bab047379469e10e27"),
   "uuid":"bbde4bba-062b-4024-9bb0-8b12656afa7e",
   "version":2,
   "categories":["sport", "shopping"]
   },
   {
   "_id":ObjectId("5744b6359c408cea15964d15"),
   "uuid":"561c3705-ba6d-432b-98fb-254483fcbefa",
   "version":1,
   "categories":["politics"]
   }
```

I want to count the number of documents for every category. To do this, I unwind the categories array:

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
 {$unwind: '$categories'}, 
 {$group: {_id: '$categories', count: {$sum: 1}} } 
)
```

Result:

```
   { "_id" : "sport", "count" : 2 }
   { "_id" : "shopping", "count" : 1 }
   { "_id" : "politics", "count" : 1 }
```

Now I want to count the number of documents for every category, but where document version is the latest version.

This is where I am stuck.

Comment: What is the latest version? 1 or 2? or even varies between documents? Same UUID?

Comment: Yes, the same uuid. Latest version is 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ugly but I think this gives you what you're after:

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
 { $unwind : "$categories" },
 { $group : 
   { "_id" : { "uuid" : "$uuid" },
     "doc" : { $push : { "version" : "$version", "category" : "$categories" } },
     "maxVersion" : { $max : "$version" } 
   }
 },
 { $unwind : "$doc" },
 { $project : { "_id" : 0, "uuid" : "$id.uuid", "category" : "$doc.category", "isCurrentVersion" : { $eq : [ "$doc.version", "$maxVersion" ] } } },
 { $match : { "isCurrentVersion" : true }},
 { $group : { "_id" : "$category", "count" : { $sum : 1 } } }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first grouping the denormalized documents (from the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator step) by two keys, i.e. the `categories` and `version` fields. This is necessary for the preceding pipeline step which orders the grouped documents and their accumulated counts by the version (desc) and categories (asc) keys respectively using the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** operator.

Another grouping will be required to get the top documents in each `categories` group after ordering using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator. The following shows this

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
    { "$unwind": "$categories" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                'categories': '$categories',
                'version': '$version'               
            }, 
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        } 
    },
    { "$sort": { "_id.version": -1, "_id.categories": 1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.categories",
            "count": { "$first": "$count" },
            "version": { "$first": "$_id.version" }         
        }
    }
)
```

**Sample Output**

```
{ "_id" : "shopping",  "count" : 1, "version" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "sport", "count" : 1, "version" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "politics", "count" : 1, "version" : 1 }
```

Comment: If a document is changed, for example the one with uuid:"bbde4bba-062b-4024-9bb0-8b12656afa7e", such that in version 2, categories:["shopping"], this query will output { "_id" : "sport", "count" : 1, "version" : 1 }.

Comment: Running the aggregation pipeline once again with those changes will give you the result `{ "_id" : "shopping", "count" : 1, "version" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "politics", "count" : 1, "version" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "sport", "count" : 1, "version" : 1 }` Is there something I am missing in the question that invalidates the answer?

Comment: The output, in this case should be { "_id" : "shopping", "count" : 1, "version" : 2 } { "_id" : "politics", "count" : 1, "version" : 1 } because the latest version of that document no longer contains the "sport" category.